# How to remove editor match bracket lines in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to remove the distracting match bracket lines below.

[image]

The settings that I  have used so far are:

```
{
    "editor.renderLineHighlight": "none",
    "editor.matchBrackets": "never"
}
```

Comment: use setting of `Bracket Pair Colorizer`

Comment: The lines are distracting because the opening braces are not aligned with the closing braces. I still have no idea how to make the opening braces aligned with the closing ones.

Comment: don't, why add useless white space, you already indent the code

Comment: @rioV8 Because I am not used to write with such a style. I am from C#, C++, and Python.

Comment: this is a very common C++ style, also used in C#, and Python does not have braces

Comment: somewhat related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168578

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank [rioV8 for your comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68129415/how-to-remove-editor-match-bracket-lines-in-vs-code?noredirect=1#comment120415520_68129415).

Add the following settings:

```
"bracketPairColorizer.showHorizontalScopeLine": false,
"bracketPairColorizer.showVerticalScopeLine": false
```

Answer (score 5):

On a similar issue:

Below is what I was looking for (removes vertical lines on left):

File: `settings.json`

Setting:

```
"editor.guides.indentation": false
```

Old that does not work anymore:

```
"editor.renderIndentGuides": false
```

More details: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_indent-guides

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:-

1. open settings.json ***CTRL + SHIFT + P and type "Open Settings (JSON)"***
2. paste the following code at the bottom:-

   ```
   "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
   "editor.guides.bracketPairs": "active",
   "editor.matchBrackets": "near",
   "editor.guides.highlightActiveBracketPair": false,
   ```