# How to disable highlighting matched parens in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I find this distracting:

[image]

I found the "editor.guides.highlightActiveBracketPair" setting and disabled it the settings (Ctrl+,), but nothing changed. I restarted the editor, but nothing changed. I checked ~/.config/Code/User/settings.json, and saw that it was there:

```
    "editor.guides.highlightActiveBracketPair": false,
```

But still no change.  I even added it again in a Python-specific block, because I learned how to do that when I went on a similar journey trying to change default indent for YAML files:

```
    "[python]": {
        "editor.guides.highlightActiveBracketPair": false 
    }
```

But still no change.

Comment: tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71637901/17447

Comment: naveen, I also just tried pasting all four of the config lines in that answer, just to see if it made a difference - still no change

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
    "editor.matchBrackets": "never",
```

The setting is listed in the [reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings):

```
  // Highlight matching brackets.
  "editor.matchBrackets": "always",
```

However, the reference doesn't list the possible options.  I correctly guessed "never", but afterwards, I searched for "brackets" in the app settings (Ctrl+,) and found the setting with a drop-down box with all three possible values:

- always
- near
- never